# Help with flashing stock ROM on Nokia 3.1 (Mediatek MT6750)

Tags: device-firmware, stock-rom, mediatek, nokia-3

I got my Nokia 3.1 in a bit of a weird situation trying to flash the stock ROM. I feel like it's a lost cause, but since I can still boot in recovery mode, there may still be a solution, I will explain in case someone can help.

It started when I tried to update from Android 8.0 to 10.0 (none of the previous OTA updates had worked and would always reboot in Oreo 8.0). This time, it didn't work and got the phone stuck in a boot loop.
The phone is still under warranty, but because I bought it overseas and there's no Nokia care centre here is New Zealand, I had no option but trying to repair it myself.

A wipe/factory reset didn't help, but after changing the active slot from B to A (using fastboot), it booted again in Oreo 8.0. Only problem is that I could no longer start a fresh Oreo 8.0 install without updating first and since all updates failed, I was stuck.
I suspect slot B is damaged or corrupt, hence the impossibility to update. To check it, I switched back the active slot to B after a factory reset, and that was not a great idea, the phone wouldn't even boot and looked hard-bricked.

But I still managed to use SP tool to download firmware, so I did that with the original Nokia 3.1 stock ROM (ES2).
However, I could not flash all files, I'm not too sure why.
I had the error message:
ERROR: STATUS_SEC_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER
Verified boot is enabled
Please download signed image (sutinfo-verified.img) or disable verified boot

I didn't know how to do either of these, so I skipped the three problematic files: sutinfo.img, systeminfo_a.img, and cda_a.img (not sure what they do?).

It worked and un-bricked the phone, but it now boots to recovery mode only. What puzzles me is that I also no longer have access to fastboot, even when I reboot to bootloader (as if it skipped bootloader and went straight to recovery). I suspect it is because it still boots on slot B but I don't know how I can check that or change it back to slot A without fastboot access.
I tried using adb: adb shell getprop ro.boot_suffix but although it can see the device, it failed because it says device is unauthorized. I've tried all the fixes for this I found, to no avail.

So that's where I am, able to boot to recovery (but with adb unauthorized), able to flash firmware (except those files that must be signed), and unable to access fastboot.
I'm giving up hope that it's repairable, but I'd love to at least understand what happened, if someone has any idea...

Sorry for the long story...

Comment: Is the device branded by a mobile network operator (MNO)? In this case it is possible that Nokia/HMD Global has used a different signing keys and that your device is therefore locked to firmware mages provided by that MNO.

Comment: https://blog.hovatek.com/so-whats-all-this-talk-about-meditek-secure-boot-and-da-files

Comment: @Robert Thanks, the device is not branded by a MNO here.

Comment: @alecxs Thanks for the link, it explains a lot. Hovatek does not have the DA file for the Nokia 3.1, but I will try the one for Nokia 3 (MT6737) and Nokia 2.2 (MT6761) just in case.

Comment: @alexcs Regarding entering fastboot mode. I have tried both methods, it used to work but it no longer does. I think at some point, when nothing else worked, I tried for flash with "Format all + Download". This may have caused the problem as 3 files couldn't be flashed because of verified boot...

Comment: No, I didn't do a readback unfortunately. It was a bit of a last resort. I guess I should have asked for help earlier. Just to understand, does the "format all + download" formats the entire phone first or just each partition before overwriting them? Would it format partition that it cannot write on because of the verified boot?

Comment: yes it did format the entire emmc, even the secro seccfg partitions, which destroyed the availbility to use SP Flash Tool. even if you manage to flash stock ROM now there is still persist partition missing (IMEI + calibration). i recommend you to claim it under warranty because it wasn't your fault. just don't tell them anything other besides the failed OTA

Comment: if recovery still working, one thing you can try is use osm0sis' AIK to unpack recovery.img, enable adb (ro.adb.secure=0), repack recovery.img (AVBv1 signed) and try to flash. once you have root access in adb shell you can restore all partitions you have backup for (to both slots) by-passing signature check. it should even possible to root on locked bootloader and fix boot loop (doesn't work for AVBv2)

Comment: IMEI repair seems possible too https://androidmtk.com/use-sn-write-tool

Comment: Wow that's a lot of good ideas, thanks a lot. Give me a few days to try them (I'm slow as I learn most of it as I go) and I'll let you know how things work.

Comment: An update on my (non-)progress so far:

- Following the advice there: https://blog.hovatek.com/so-whats-all-this-talk-about-meditek-secure-boot-and-da-files
I have tried to find different download DA files, but none of them were recognized by sp flash tool, so couldn't try to flash with them.

- I have tried to readback the EMMC_BOOT partition and the EMMC_USER partition in sp flash tool, but that also failed, not sure why.

- I have tried flashing using the Online Service Tool. It seems to start ok, but then encounters some error, I assume because the bootloader isn't unlocked.

Comment: - I have also tried adb sideload from the recovery, and this seems to be possible. However, I have tried to use it to flash several stock firmware and
always got the error "Footer is wrong", something about needing signed files. I guess it's the AVB that is causing issue.
I couldn't find an OTA update.zip for Nokia 3.1, so coudn't try that.

Comment: - I have access to the recovery log from the recovery mode
The begining goes like this:
"fail to open /sys/class/ BOOT/BOOT/boot/boot_type"
"get device_type from ro.mtk_ufs_booting for ufs devices
"platform device_type is unknown"
"platform uses default device_type emmc"
"Error: Retry fail/cache partition not found"
I don't understand all of it, but it sure doesn't look good. It's weird because I have flashed the stock ROM with sp flash tool, including preloader, kernel (lk_a), boot_a, secro.
The only partition I can't flash are sutinfo, system_a and cda_a.

Comment: All in all, it's not looking good, but I'll try a few more things next week end before I give up.

Comment: find an OTA update.zip for Nokia 3.1 (which is signed, for stock recovery)

Comment: I have tried finding an OTA update.zip, but without success, so at this stage I have given up... Thanks a lot for your help anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem as you, after looking in a lot of forums I managed to solve it, I hope it helps you.
My phone was no longer able to access the recovery, nor fastboot. After trying lots of Rom and various methods, I will explain to you which one I recovered the mobile, that is, losing the Imei, but for that there are many valid solutions.
Enter the page https://www.needrom.com/download/nokia-3-1/
You have to create a premium account to download, but they are 3USD for 1 month, download the Rom and the flashtool from that link, when it flashes put it in Firmware Upgrade mode and uncheck the preloader, sutinfo, systeminfo and cda boxes.
It worked perfectly for me and after that he let me update via OTA to Android 10.
Greetings.

Comment: can you share *MTK_AllInOne_DA.bin + auth_sv5.auth + sutinfo-verified.img + boot-verified.img + recovery-verified.img* for this device